# Get the last value appears in column Y for unique value appears in column X

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, awk, nawk

I hope the title is not confusing.. I have a daily report file contains information about regular retailers, their transactions and their balance after each transaction. example:

```
  TransactionDate;retailerName;retailersBalance;retailersNewBalance;TrAmount;TaxAmount
   2020-03-28 23:59:00;ret1;522305800;522300200;5040;560
   2020-03-28 18:47:04;ret2;3166007400;3165997400;9000;1000
   2020-03-28 16:43:10;ret1;522311400;522305800;5040;560;
```

Retailer might have more than one transaction, his balance (retailersNewBalance) keeps on changing as much as he does transactions.
I need to generate a report using shell script to print out the recent balance (retailersNewBalance) for each retailer. notice that, the ret1 exists twice on this example report (at 23:59:00 and at 16:43:10) and could me more

The expected output should be the last (recent) retailers New Balance. ex:

```
   Time    Retailers  Balance
 ================================
 23:59:00   ret1     522300200
 18:47:04   ret2     3165997400
```

Comment: Add the expected output to your question.

Comment: question has been updated

Comment: Is the input file sorted by date? Are the most recent balances always toward the beginning of input file (as in the example)?

Comment: Yes, the most recent balances always toward the beginning of input file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If input is sorted by date, with most recent first:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=";"} FNR>1 && !nameseen[$2]++ {print $1, $2, $4}' file
```

- only print the record if the field from the "retailerName" column has not been seen

---

Example with some formatting:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    FS=";"
    printf "%9s\t%-20s\t%s\n", "Time", "Retailers", "Balance"
}
FNR>1 && !nameseen[$2]++ {
    split($1,time," ")
    printf "%9s\t%-20s\t%s\n", time[2], $2, $4
}' file
```

Comment: the input file header is coming on the output. How can ignore it

Comment: `FNR>1` may need adjusting. This tells awk to ignore initial records. Try increasing this number to suit the input.

Comment: how can i add a separator like "=====" after the header?

Comment: @Fshamri  In the `BEGIN` actions, add a new line: `print "====="`